# Multiple JMS configurations in application.yml when using Micronaut JMS

Tags: jms, micronaut

I'm using Micronaut JMS version 2.1.0. My `application.yml` is as below:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: jms-tester
  jms:
    activemq:
      artemis:
        enabled: true
        connection-string: tcp://192.168.10.64:61616
```

What if I have two or more MQ to connect? For example, I have another completely separate MQ at `tcp://192.168.11.64:61616`. How should I configure `application.yml`?

Comment: Please elaborate on your broker configuration. Are the two brokers configured as a primary/backup pair for high-availability or are they configured in a cluster for load-balancing or are they just completely separate brokers and you want your application to interact with both of them?

Comment: my two brokers are completely separate brokers. So I can not configure them in failover connection string. Well, I just dejava Micronaut JMS jar files can realized that the current architecture in Micronaut JMS seems to unable to config multiple standalone MQ.